# Eclipse Hibernate.cfg.xml is linking "sys" database from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate-tools

When I use Hibernate to connect to a MySQL database, *bookstoredb*, in Eclipse, a connection to the MySQL *sys* database also shows up!

[image]

I'm using the following:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (desktop)
- Eclipse 2020-6 (4.16.0) w/JBoss Tools, Hibernate-Tools plugin.
- MySQL Ver 8.0.21 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Note: this is a local desktop project, I am working through a tutorial. I will NOT be using root/admin with MySQL down the road.

Following is the complete hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredb?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Am I misunderstanding, shouldn't the connection.url, as given, ONLY connect to *bookstoredb*? Why is "sys" connecting also?

This becomes even more of a problem when using the tool to reverse-engineer the database tables into java classes. I'm getting not only the *bookstoredb* tables as java classes but every table in the *sys* database as well. And there are a lot of them, as I am sure folks well know.

How do I unlink the *sys* database? Or set things up so I don't link to it in the first place?

Comment: Ended up reinstalling Eclipse and rebuilding the project with newer versions of the components. And skipped using the Hibernate Reverse Engineering tool altogether. So, I guess this just goes unresolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess sys is the default schema in your MySQL workbench.

Go to your Mysql workbench and drop the schema/because it is importing all the schemas from your local server.

or

Custom :- Open your workspace(eclipse("run" tab on top of screen->hibernate code genration) -> Go to hibernate code generation( -> click main-> revenge.xml->select new -> select folder-> configure table filter-> (1)select database you want to select-> import all table-> apply -> Run .

Now you can see all the tables in the location you have selected.
If you want to customer export you could also do so after (1) step above

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because it includes good information and sounds reasonable. But I should add, I didn't actually do the answer. Instead, as mentioned in the original post, I ended up starting the project over. Something got scrambled up somehow, and in the second iteration, the problem did not turn up.

Answer (score 1):

For those with a similar issue to this. Hibernate tools reverse engineering reads all schemas. Therefor specifying the database doesn't work. So you need a custom schema selection tag to specify which database you want reverse engineer from. This is done by creating a `hibernate.reveng.xml` file and adding something like this where `demo` is the name of the database

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering SYSTEM "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <schema-selection match-catalog="demo" match-schema=".*" match-table=".*"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```